# Unable to run flow in cordapp-template-java

Tags: corda

I have configure sample project of cordapp-template-java and all node and notary node has started successfully. However when running flow it is throwing error

I have run the command "start flow Initiator" but got below error
No matching constructor found:

- [sendTo: Party]: missing parameter sendTo

After reading couple of threads on stackoverflow I run below command
start IOUFlow arg0: 99, arg1: "O=PartyB,L=New York,C=US"

However I got different error now as below

Thu Jul 29 17:47:55 IST 2021>>> start flow Initiator "Bharat"
Ambiguous name provided, please be more specific. Your options are:

1. com.template.flows.Initiator
2. net.corda.core.flows.ContractUpgradeFlow$Initiate
3. net.corda.core.flows.ContractUpgradeFlow$Authorise
4. net.corda.core.flows.ContractUpgradeFlow$Deauthorise

Any help is appreciated..!!

Comment: Did you follow the documentation mentioned in the README https://github.com/corda/cordapp-template-java? https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.8/tutorial-cordapp.html
It is described how to run the flow.

Comment: Can you paste your flow code here please.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using a malformed format to trigger the flow. Here is the format you need to use:

```
start flow <flowname> <param_1_name>: <param_1_value>, ..., <param_N_name>: <param_N_value>
```